# How to implement the KDJ indicator calculation in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to Implement the KDJ Indicator Caluculation AND also CIPHER B Calculation in Highcharts ?
KDJ Forumula ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a list of all built-in indicators: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/technical-indicator-series

If you need to use some other indicator, you need to create it by following these steps:: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/custom-technical-indicators

Comment: Thank you . I need the KDJ calculation, Cipher B trading calculation formula.

Comment: Hi @gunasaras, That is not a build-in indicator, you need to create it.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , Thank you. 

How to do customize the new indicators in Tradingview chart on my local ? not in buildin indicators.

Comment: What is the exact problem? I think that in the link I provided you have a very accurate description of how you can create your own indicator.

Comment: https://in.tradingview.com/script/h51ZIRlX-KDJ-Indicator-iamaltcoin/
This is the example link for KDJ indicator. 
how to integrate the exact chart in local on tradingview chart

Comment: As I said before, you need to follow the steps from the documentation and create custom technical indicator. You can also contact blacklabel company: https://www.blacklabel.pl/ if you want someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

You can use the stochastic indicator that calculates %K and %D and then create a custom indicator to calculate the %J value.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to create a complete KDJ indicator but have to include one series for stochastic indicator (%K and %D) and one series for the custom indicator (%J).

The custom KDJ indicator has to be linked to the stochastic series:

```
{
  type: 'kdj'
  linkedTo: 'myStochasticSeriesId',
  ...
}
```

Here's my KDJ (%J) indicator (using TypeScript):

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

function getJ(xData: any, yData: any) {
  return {
    xData,
    yData,
    values: yData.map((stochasticValues: [number, number]) => {
      const [k, d] = stochasticValues;
      const j = 3 * d - 2 * k;
      return j;
    }),
  };
}

export default function (highcharts: typeof Highcharts) {
  highcharts.seriesType(
    'kdj', // Calculates %J from %K and %D
    'stochastic', // Calculates %K & %D
    {
      name: 'KDJ'
    },
    {
      getValues: function (series: any): any {
        return this.getKDJ(series.xData, series.yData);
      },
      getKDJ: getJ
    }
  );
}
```

And you have to initialize the KDJ indicator just like other indicators:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import kdj from './indicators/kdj-indicator';
kdj(Highcharts);
```